# Integrate hibernate-validator with wicket

Tags: java, hibernate, wicket, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have some entities with some fields annotated with hibernate-validator annotations like:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Z,0-9]{3,}")
    @Column
    private String key;

    @Range(min = 1, max = 999)
    @Column
    private Integer year;

    // [...]
}
```

Is there any way to make use of thoose validator annotations in wicket components (like forms)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer for myself:

hibernate-validator is just an implementation of java-bean-validation (javax.validation,  JSR-303).

Since Wicket 6.4.0 there is a support in wicket for java-bean-validation.

1) add wicket-bean-validation to you project, e.g with maven:

```
<groupId>org.apache.wicket<groupId> 
<artifactId>wicket-bean-validation</artifactId> 
<version>0.5</version>
```

2) Add PropertyValidator to your wicket-fields, like:

```
form.add(new TextField("key", new PropertyModel(myModel, "key")) .add(new PropertyValidator()))
form.add(new TextField("year", new PropertyModel(myModel, "year")) .add(new PropertyValidator()))
```

The rest do wicket and hibernate-validator for you ...